# How can I get and compare a Sprite name on Android?

Tags: java, android, sprite

I have next code in a game:

```
for (int i = sprites.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i); //Get the Sprite

    if (sprite.isCollision(event.getX(),event.getY())) {
        sprites.remove(sprite);  //Delete character

        temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));  //Add blood mark

        //I NEED TO DO THIS  =)

        if (sprite.getName() == "witch"){
            sounds.play(sBad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f); }

        else{  //Is a mummy
            sounds2.play(sBad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f); } 
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

How Can I get the "Sprite Name" or the "Sprite ID" to compare with a String??

Thanks a lot fellas

Comment: use `equals()` method to compare Strings. don't use `==` operator. You have used at `if (sprite.getName() == "witch")`...

Comment: Add a member String variable, e.g. `String mName`, to your `Sprite` class, and implement a setter and getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Compare the String using `equals()` or with `equalsIgnoreCase()` in android

`==` is used to compare the reference of the two  object

change this `if(sprite.getName() == "witch")` with `(sprite.getName().equals("witch"))`

Comment: Hi
I know that instruction

The problem is that a Sprite doesn't have a method getName()
the Sprite is a bitMap

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

`sprite.getName().toString().equals("witch")`

or:

`sprite.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("witch")`

Comment: Hi
I know that instruction

The problem is that a Sprite doesn't have a method getName()
the Sprite is a bitMap